# STM32 HAL SPI Interrupt Handling

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32, spi, hal

Im using the STM32F4xx and want to learn to programm with the ST-HAL. 
In the moment I try to send/ receive SPI over interrupts.

I used the following functions to receive data over INT.:

Init function:

```
void HAL_MspInit(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 0 */

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_0);

  /* System interrupt init*/
  /* MemoryManagement_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(MemoryManagement_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* BusFault_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(BusFault_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* UsageFault_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(UsageFault_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* SVCall_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SVCall_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* DebugMonitor_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DebugMonitor_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* PendSV_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(PendSV_IRQn, 0, 0);
  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 1 */
    /* Peripheral interrupt init */

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 1, 1); //<--------------------
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);         //<--------------------

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 1 */
}
```

Start function:

```
void main(void)
{
    HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi1, buff, size);//Start the receiving process?   

    while(1)
    {
     . . . 
    }
}
```

Interrputhandler:

```
void SPI1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_SPI_IRQHandler(&hspi1);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_IRQn 1 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Callbackfunction (defined in main file):

```
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
    volatile uint8_t y = 5;
}
```

Before my question: Using the "normal" SPI_Transmit&Receive functions, I transmit & receive correctly.

My problem is that I dont understand how I should use this functions. 
e.g.: Where should I call the start" function" when comes the Callback function, an do I have to clear Interruptflags, and so on...

At the moment I use "HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT" & "HAL_SPI_Receive_IT" in the while(1) loop. In the Rx and Tx callbackfunctions I have counter variables. I see that the tmpCounterRx counts up but the tmpCounterTx dosnt???

E.G.:

```
while (1)
{
    HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi1, buff, size);
    HAL_Delay(500);
    HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi1, buff, size);  
}
}

void HAL_SPI_TxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
    tmpCounterTx++;
    volatile uint8_t x = 5;
}

void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
    tmpCounterRx++;
    volatile uint8_t y = 5;
}
```

Rev. 1:

Thanks for reply, here my SPI init function:

```
void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
    hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
    hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
    hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
    hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;

    if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your SPI init code please.

Comment: I would suggest the bare register approach.

Comment: Hm... I liked the way which interrupt handling works with the StdLib. But I have to learn using HAL and I dont know if its recomended to mix HAL and bare register approach ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I assume that counters are `volatile`. At least you will know what interrupts are triggered and if it a HAL callback configuration problem.

```
volatile uint32_t tmpCounterRx1 = 0, tmpCounterTx1 = 0;

void SPI1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if((SPI1 -> SR & SPI_SR_RXNE)) 
  {
    tmpCounterRx1++;
  } else    // intentional else do not remove
  if((SPI1 -> SR & SPI_SR_TXE)) 
  {
    tmpCounterTx1++;
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_SPI_IRQHandler(&hspi1);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_IRQn 1 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

PS I know it should be the comment but it is quite difficult to place longer pieces of the code in comments

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! I can confirm that the interrupt trigger. But the problem that interrupt triggered SPI communication have no effect to writing or reading my EEPROM. Damn!

Comment: now you have to connect the logic analyser. No other way. Check if you have the correct clock polarity and active edge. Some time ago I have tried to use HAL (I was just curious). For anything less complex than USB or Ethernet is just not worth.

Comment: Yes I total agree. Basically I learned that the ISR shall as short as possible. But if I see how many code only the HAL_SPI_IRQHandler() has, it seems to be not very efficent. Am I wrong? Anyway, do you think ist "ok" to mix HAL and own bare metal ISR handling?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in it. The only pointless part is if mix for the same hardware. HAL has a lots of bugs as well, and the only point of using it is the faster track of some certification. http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-classb.html